# GWT клиент. Как получить уникальный ID ?

Tags: gwt, java

Вопрос скорее теоретический, на практике видимо достаточно System.currentTimeMillis();

Хотелось бы получить IP, pid браузера (м.б. environment) и т.п. Не нашел, как это можно достать из клиента
(java, компилируемая в JS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Как уникальный `ID` можно использовать специально предназначенный для этого `UUID`.**

Поскольку `GWT` [не поддерживает `UUID`](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) на клиентской части, то необходимо использовать некоторую альтернативную реализацию, которая будет поддерживаться `client-side:`

```
public class UUID {
    private static final char[] CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray(); 
    /**
     * Generate a random uuid of the specified length. Example: uuid(15) returns
     * "VcydxgltxrVZSTV"
     * 
     * @param len
     *            the desired number of characters
     */
    public static String uuid(int len) {
        return uuid(len, CHARS.length);
    }
    /**
     * Generate a random uuid of the specified length, and radix. Examples:
     * <ul>
     * <li>uuid(8, 2) returns "01001010" (8 character ID, base=2)
     * <li>uuid(8, 10) returns "47473046" (8 character ID, base=10)
     * <li>uuid(8, 16) returns "098F4D35" (8 character ID, base=16)
     * </ul>
     * 
     * @param len
     *            the desired number of characters
     * @param radix
     *            the number of allowable values for each character (must be <=
     *            62)
     */
    public static String uuid(int len, int radix) {
        if (radix > CHARS.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        char[] uuid = new char[len];
        // Compact form
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            uuid[i] = CHARS[(int)(Math.random()*radix)];
        }
        return new String(uuid);
    }
    /**
     * Generate a RFC4122, version 4 ID. Example:
     * "92329D39-6F5C-4520-ABFC-AAB64544E172"
     */
    public static String uuid() {
        char[] uuid = new char[36];
        int r;

        // rfc4122 requires these characters
        uuid[8] = uuid[13] = uuid[18] = uuid[23] = '-';
        uuid[14] = '4';

        // Fill in random data.  At i==19 set the high bits of clock sequence as
        // per rfc4122, sec. 4.1.5
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
            if (uuid[i] == 0) {
                r = (int) (Math.random()*16);
                uuid[i] = CHARS[(i == 19) ? (r & 0x3) | 0x8 : r & 0xf];
            }
        }
        return new String(uuid);
    }
}
```

**2. IP Клиента.**

Для получения информации об `IP` клиента необходимо сервлет унаследовать от `RemoteServiceServlet` и использовать метод `getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr()`.

Сделать это **целиком** на клиентской части, разумеется, не представляется возможным.

**3. Получить `PID` браузера невозможно, т.к `javascript` не имеет доступа к `PID` в принципе.**

Получить же, например, тип браузера можно несложным образом с помощью метода `JSNI`:

```
 public static native String getUserAgent() /*-{
     return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 }-*/;
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Весьма исчерпывающий (и главное очень конкретный) ответ.